# Blender => Unity Export, UV Coloring

Tags: unity

I have struggles with Importing my Blend to Unity with the Colors i mapped it in Blender.
In Blender the Colors are the way I want them.
I can get the Object in to Unity, as an Object,
in Unity I either  get a Blank Object or complettly misscolored Object.

My Object in Blender
[image: My Object in Blender]

This is the Method I used to color my Objects,
using the UV Editing.
[image: Blender UV coloring Method]

When Imported to unity the UV colors are wrong.
[image: My Object in Untiy]

I have Tryd the Folowing things:

Creating a New Simple Cube With same UV Editing method to see if problem persists.
With the ressult being exact the same Problem that was in Unity as with my Modell.

Tryd editing the Material Tilt and Offset in Unity to correct the Colors
wich only changed colors without finding the Color arrangement I was searching for

Importing the .blend File trough Drag and Drop to Unity

Importing the .fbx file and tryng to add the Material after adding the empty Modells

I also tryd messing with diffrent setting whilst exporting

Restarting everything

When I open the exported .fbx file in windows everything is normal as it shoud be.

These are some atempts I tryd, I woud realy Appriciate help,
for I have been tryng to find a sloution over the last 6 Houres,
reading all over the Internet and looking up tutorials for a solution.

Thx in Addvance

-Josh

(Sorry for bad Grammar)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was Solved,

The .fbx file was all fine

In Unity I Created a new Material and Dragged my Texture file,
from the UV Editing onto the Albedo of the Material.

After That the Colors will be wrong, so you need to change some settings of the Texture.

Compression => None,
Filter Mode => Point(No Filter)

Comment: Instead of wrinting "solved" mark the answer as accepted.