# Export objects with materials

Tags: texturing, materials, export, unity

I've tried to export an object with materials, but the windows 3D Viewer shows a white cube ( Unity too :( ).
I use Cycles, textures got baked. [image]

My shaders: [image]

And my result: [image]

I tried Path Mode: Copy in the export menu, but nothing helps.

Comment: Are https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24422/export-cycles-material-to-unity or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/193645/blender-unity-export-uv-coloring duplicates of your question?

Comment: IMHO, no. Sorry, but I am really beginner in blender, and have no clue about that, but as i said, it's not just unity, i cant event see the textures in  the Windows' 3D Viewer.

Comment: Okay, so what i know: With color ramp, the texture is not baked(?) If i do not include color ramp, I can export the object with textures.

Comment: Hi, which format are you exporting? GLTF/GLB is good to embed materials and textures, and the result is good ok for Unity as well as Windows 3D Viewer. It's ok that you bake the color ramp, but then you have to create a shader in a specific way with the baked textures to keep the materials embedded in the output file (check this guide https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html).